# How to start slicing from the second line?

Tags: python, list, slice

My current code reads the 1st line, then 3rd, 5th, 7th and so on and adds it to a list.

I want it to read the 2nd, 4th, 6th lines ... and add it to another list.

```
with open(path) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content[::2]]
```

Comment: `content[1::2]`

Comment: Kindly add it to answers so i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start slicing by skipping the first item; here is an example:

```
>>> list(i)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> list(i[1::2])
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

In your code:

```
content = [x.strip() for x in content[1::2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a start to your slice of `1`, e.g. `content[1::2]`:

```
with open(path) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

content = [x.strip() for x in content[1::2]]
```

A better alternative would be to use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to do this, as follows:

```
from itertools import islice

with open(path) as f_input:
    content = [line.strip() for line  in islice(f_input, 1, None, 2)]
```

Answer (score -1):

***your code should be like that
meaning that the slice starts from 1 to the end of the list with a step of two.***

```
with open(path) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

content = [x.strip() for x in content[1::2]]
from itertools import islice

with open(path) as f_input:
    content = [line.strip() for line  in islice(f_input, 1, None, 2)]
```